# pyOpenGL: trouble creating a direction ray

Tags: python, opengl

I am working on a program in python OCC where the user can click the screen, which will send the ray out based on window coordinates. I wrote a ray direction function, but even when the mouse moves, the values in the direction vector dont change much at all, the biggest change in value i have seen is in the 14th decimal point of each x, y, and z value. I was curious if I have a problem in my code.

My code is pictured below:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtOpenGL, QtWidgets
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

def generate_ray(mouse_x, mouse_y):

    projection_matrix = glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX)
    model_matrix = glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)
    view_matrix = glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT)

    corrected_y = view_matrix[3] - mouse_y

    near_x, near_y, near_z = gluUnProject(mouse_x,corrected_y,0,model_matrix,projection_matrix,view_matrix)
    far_x, far_y, far_z = gluUnProject(mouse_x,corrected_y,1,model_matrix,projection_matrix,view_matrix)

    direction = [far_x - near_x]
    direction.append(far_y - near_y)
    direction.append(far_z - near_z)

    print("ray direction: x: {} y: {} z: {}".format(direction[0], direction[1], direction[2]))
    return direction
```

If this helps, my ray-triangle intersection test is below. the ray direction, origin, and vertice list are all numpy arrays.

```
import numpy

def crossProduct(x1, x2):

    """array[0] is the x-coord, array[1] is the y coord, and array[2] is the z coord """   
    COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3
    cross_product_array = numpy.empty([COORDS_PER_VERTEX])
    #print(x1[0])
    #print(x2[2])
    cross_product_array[0] = x1[1] * x2[2] - x1[2] * x2[1]
    cross_product_array[1] = x1[2] * x2[0] - x1[0] * x2[2]
    cross_product_array[2] = x1[0] * x2[1] - x1[1] * x2[0]  
    return cross_product_array

def dotProduct(x1, x2):
    """array[0] is the x-coord, array[1] is the y coord, and array[2] is the z coord """
    result = x1[0] * x2[0] + x1[1]  * x2[1] + x1[2] * x2[2]
    return result

def ray_triangle_intersection_test(ray_origin, ray_direction, vertice_list):
    EPSILON = 0.0000001 
    NEG_EPSILON = -0.0000001 

    edge1 = vertice_list[1] - vertice_list[0]
    #print(edge1)
    edge2 = vertice_list[2] - vertice_list[0]
    #print(edge2)
    pvec = crossProduct(ray_direction,edge2)
    print("pvec: %s" %pvec)
    det = dotProduct(edge1,pvec)
    print("det: %s" %det)
    if det > NEG_EPSILON and det < EPSILON:
        print("parallel")
        return # This ray is parallel to this triangle.
    invDet = 1.0/det
    print("invDet: %s" %invDet)
    svec = ray_origin - vertice_list[0]
    u = invDet * (dotProduct(svec,pvec))
    print("u: %s" %u)
    """
    if u < 0.0 or u > 1.0:
        print("false1")
        return 
    """
    qvec = crossProduct(svec, edge1)
    v = invDet * dotProduct(ray_direction, qvec)
    """
    if v < 0.0 or u + v > 1.0:
        print("false2")
        return
    """
    # At this stage we can compute t to find out where the intersection point is on the line.
    t = invDet * dotProduct(edge2, qvec)
    print("t: %s" %t)
    if t > EPSILON: # ray intersection
        outIntersectionPoint = numpy.multiply((ray_origin + ray_direction),t) 
        return outIntersectionPoint 
    else: # This means that there is det line intersection but not det ray intersection.
        print("false3")
        return
```

Comment: Note you calculate a direction and not a point. The direction points from the near plane to the far plane along the line of sight. If you would use orthographic projection (parallel projection), then the direction would be the same for each point on the viewport. In this case the direction depends only on the `model_matrix`.

Comment: That is correct, I do use orthographic projection. So the direction will always be the same with orthographic?

Comment: For the same `model_matrix` it will be the same direction.

Comment: Yes, the direction is the same in an orthographic view. That's what an orthographic view is, really.

Comment: What is the best way to select a specific point on a shape by clicking on the viewport? I'd like the program to return the specific point of the shape that was clicked, if possible.